# Vue "npm run build" Ignores vue.config.js File

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

I have a Webpack-templated Vue project, initiated through vue-cli.

I have created a simple '*vue.config.js*' file stored in the root folder *(where package.json is at)* containing the following:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  productionSourceMap: false
}
```

Though when building the project using "npm run build" it ignores it.

I have tried different configurations to check if the problem is with the file or the setting, and the problem is with the file.

I am using *webpack@3.12.0*, *vue@2.6.11*, *@vue/cli 4.2.3* and *npm@6.9.0*.

Comment: can you show your package.json file plz.

Comment: @michmich112 added 

Comment: can you also add your `build/build.js` file plz?

Comment: @michmich112 added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I did not manage to get vue.config.js to work.

Alternatively, I edited my *webpack* config, which as my build files mentioned was located at /config/index.js
Then, I proceeded to pass my build configurations to the build parameter which already appears on the file.

```
build: {
  ...
}
```

And it worked. I assume it may be because I used npm run dev instead of the vue-service-cli, so webpack did not go through the vue.config.js file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your build confiuration (in your case the webpack build configs) include your file.

Generally, you will have a source folder (often `src`) and the builder will build all the files in that dir only. Then you have your destination directory (often `dist` or `build`) where your build files will be stored.

Two solutions:

1. add your conf file to the build source.
2. move your vue.conf.js file into your source directory

Comment: Are you referring to *build/webpack.prod.conf.js*? How do I include the *vue.config.js* file?

Comment: its the config file thats specified in your `build/build.js`. the file that is required by this import: `const config = require('../config')`

Comment: ended up changing the config on the file itself (directly on config/index.js) which worked. I didn't see any mentioning of vue.config.js there, is it a new thing?